# The incompatible between windows builder versions and java versions and eclipse version

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, swing, builder

I encounter this problem as below:
"Eclipse is running under 0, butthis Java project has a 1.8 Java compliance level, so WindowBuilder will not be able to load classesfrom this project. Use a lower level of Java for the project, or run Eclipse using a newer Javaversion. "

I tried several ways but it did not work. I installed both java 17 and java 1.8 and changed the jre to 1.8 & the complier to 1.8. In the end, it still did not work.
The eclipse version I am using is 2018. I need it to start the SWING application and now I am into troubles.
Can you give me some suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is 2022. Have you considered using the latest version of Eclipse? You can have both versions on your harddrive side by side, in case you need to go back. Make a backup copy of the project/workspace, too.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I tried but it did not work. I installed both eclipse 2022 & 2018 and it still did not work. Now I gave up and switched to another IDE